# Can I better compress multiple SQLite3 DB's individually or altogether?

Tags: sqlite, compression, gzip, gzipstream

I am working on a program in C# that deals with multiple database files at once to create a sort of cache that a user can choose later to compress and archive. I am using SQLite3 for these databases. However, when it came to compression, I noticed that for the SQLite connection string, there is an optional parameter for compression that can be enabled. Another option is to just run all of the database files through a GZip stream. The last option is to do both.

What I am wondering is what option would, on average, result in the smallest disk usage after compression? I figured that SQLite probably knows better than me how to compress its own database files, however that works on a per file basis. GZip can take advantage of data across files to better compress files, however if the SQLite databases are already compressed, it might reduce the cross file data that a GZip stream can use to make a smaller output.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't ever seen any results from using the `compress=true` verses not. I have seen really good compression of the SQLite database file using ZIP or 7-ZIP.